# How do you send a typing bubble to FB messenger via Flask and pymessenger?

Tags: python, flask, chatbot, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm building a chatbot deployed via FB messenger. According to FB documentation, you have to send [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/sender-actions/) post request to the messenger platform. I send a string representation of the payload using json.dumps. However, I never see the typing bubble and only get the actual response message from the bot. Here is the pertinent code from the Flask app.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_message():
    global tag, latest_message
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Before allowing people to message your bot Facebook has implemented a verify token
        # that confirms all requests that your bot receives came from Facebook.
        token_sent = request.args.get("hub.verify_token")
        return verify_fb_token(token_sent)
    # If the request was not GET, it  must be POSTand we can just proceed with sending a message
    # back to user
    else:
            # get whatever message a user sent the bot
        output = request.get_json()
        for event in output['entry']:
            messaging = event['messaging']
            for message in messaging:
                if message.get('message'):
                    # Facebook Messenger ID for user so we know where to send response back to
                    recipient_id = message['sender']['id']
                    typing_payload = json.dumps({"recipient":{"id":recipient_id}, "sender_action":"typing_on"})
                    bot.send_raw(typing_payload)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    if message['message'].get('text'):
                        response_sent_text = send(message['message'].get('text'))
                        send_message(recipient_id, response_sent_text)
                        latest_message = response_sent_text
    return "Message Processed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pymessenger wrapper. Just import it, create an instance and pass your FB_TOKEN and wrap your actions. Remember when sending action, Facebook doc state that you must only pass the recipient_id and action and call the method separate from the response.
set action to "typing_on" in your method.

NB: Your method is incorrect because you are mixing sender_id and recipient_id

```
from pymessenger import Bot
bot = Bot(<FB_ACCESS_TOKEN>)
def send_typing_bubble(sender_id, recipient_id, action, response_sent_text):
    bot.send_action(sender_id, action)
    bot.send_text_message(sender_id, response_sent_text)
```

After your create the method you can just call send_typing_bubble() inside your webhook receive_message() method

```
if messaging_event.get('message'):

   #your code here

   send_typing_bubble(sender_id, recipient_id, action, 
       response_sent_text)
```